# Android - slide animation to scroll in fragments

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, scroll

I have created 10 fragments with the code below to make scroll with your finger from right to left and left to right.

How I can add "Animation" the scroll of the fragments to not be the default animation adapted my code? Thank you

**JAVA**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.detalle_monumento_view);

    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();

    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);      
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

private List<Fragment> getFragments(){

    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        fList.add(DetalleMonumentoFragment.newInstance());
    }

    return fList;
}

private class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement key listener ,Then check Right to left swipe or Left to right swipe and add your logic in that particular condition.

Comment: This link will be useful for you  [Swipe event](http://androidexample.com/Swipe_screen_left__right__top_bottom/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=95&aaid=118)